# Segmentation fault (core dumped), when using xxdiff with matlab file.m

Tags: fedora, cinnamon

I do not succeed to use the, very useful, xxdiff command line, with MATLAB file.m.  The result is a 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' error message and a cascade windows corresponding to the current Desktop in the xxdiff window. As an example:

```
xxdiff spatial1.m spatial2.m
```

gives the following cascade window, in addition to of the 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' error message ...

[image]

Comment: what is the content of these `.m` files? If you edit/view them, are they pure text? Perhaps if they contain very long lines, this may cause `xxdiff` to crash but it would be a bug. Perhaps you can try with regular `diff` or `sdiff`.

Comment: Yes it is pure text, except that the carriage return is ^M. With diff and sdiff, no error messages, but it does not do really the job (I can compare the two files by using the visdiff command in Matlab, but I would like understand why xxdiff does not work here!). Thanks for your interesting remarks.

Comment: I would suggest to first try again with the latest version, then check for known bugs on the xxdiff bug list (see http://sourceforge.net/p/xxdiff/bugs/) or possibly create a ticket yourself. You'll likely need to add the two `.m` files to let them reproduce the problem then.

Comment: How is this related to MATLAB language?

Comment: I don't know. The fact is that I observed this issue with two .m files ! (I use very often xxdiff and I observed this problem only with .m files till now).